# Properly sidechain_compress stereo background with stereo sidechain into stereo output

Tags: audio, filter, ffmpeg

I'm doing voiceover and since Sony Vegas does not support sidechaining, I render voiceover into voices.wav and then use [sidechain_compress filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sidechaincompress), as per [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-24):

```
ffmpeg -y -i background.m4a -i voices.wav -filter_complex \
    "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];\
    [0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.015:ratio=2:level_sc=0.8:release=500:attack=1[compr];\
    [compr][mix]amerge" sidechain_1.wav
```

`voices.wav` is a stereo audio file, as well as background.m4a. But here's how the result file looks like when loaded into Sony Vegas:

[image]

This shows that in channels 1/2 I get the compressed background, while in channel 3 and 4 I get two mono tracks that somehow differ (probably, that's the original voices input and somewhat altered voices input, both in mono). **UPD: I don't want to further process resulting tracks in Sony Vegas, I'd prefer ffmpeg to be the last step in my production process. The screenshot above is for illustration purposes only.**

1. Is the background gets sidechain compressed with only left or right channel of voices? If so, how to change that to make it compressed by both channels (some voices are panned into left or right, so there might be actual difference in compressed result)
2. What are those channels 3 and 4? Why are they mono?
3. How do I get single 1/2 stereo track in the output wav file instead of this weird 4 channels in 3 tracks? (I've looked at [pan complex filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan), but didn't figure out how to set it up in my case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

amerge adds the channels of the inputs. amix uses the channel count of the input with the most channels. So, switch to amix.

```
ffmpeg -y -i background.m4a -i voices.wav -filter_complex \
    "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];\
    [0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.015:ratio=2:level_sc=0.8:release=500:attack=1[compr];\
    [compr][mix]amix" sidechain_1.wav
```

Comment: Perhaps I put it the wrong way: I use Vegas for editing, then export voices as separate track to sidechain compress the original background. But I don't want to create new or otherwise alter the original vegas project, I'd prefer ffmpeg to be the last step. The actual last step will be the script that uses ffmpeg to combine muted HD source with voiceovered audio track.