# ffmpeg to auto lower/fade audio volume of one audio stream when microphone voice detected?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, microphone

I want to do live audio translation via microphone, to get streamed live vid/audio from Facebook, plug the mic into laptop and do live translation by mixing existing audio stream with one coming from the mic (translation). This is OK, somehow I got this part by using audio filter "amix" and mix two audio streams together into one. Now I want to add more perfection to it, is it possible to (probably is) upon mic voice detection to automatically decrease/fade down 20% volume of input/original audio stream to hear translation (mic audio) more loudly and then when mic action/voice stops for lets say 3-5 seconds the volume of original audio stream fades up/goes up to normal volume... is this too much, i can play with sox or similar?

Comment: See the [sidechaincompress](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sidechaincompress) filter.

Comment: Ok, thank you I think I found one good example of sidechaincompress sutitable for my usage but have to tweak it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276085/ffmpeg-properly-sidechain-compress-stereo-background-with-stereo-sidechain-into